# Missing memory controller

Tags: linux, memory

When I checking my rams status on one of my computers using `lshw -short -C memory`
I got the following:

```
H/W path                 Device     Class          Description
==============================================================
/0/0                                memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/58                               memory         64GiB System Memory
/0/58/0                             memory         16GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/58/1                             memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/58/2                             memory         16GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/58/3                             memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/58/4                             memory         16GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/58/5                             memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/58/6                             memory         16GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/58/7                             memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/66                               memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/67                               memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/68                               memory         15MiB L3 cache
```

however, on my other computers, they all have

```
/0/100/1f.2                 memory         Memory controller
```

at the bottom line. I am wondering why it is missing?

My specs are (just in case of need)

[Asus X99 E-WS](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/X99E_WS/), [i7 5930K](http://ark.intel.com/products/82931/Intel-Core-i7-5930K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz), 64G Ram, GTX 1080.
RAMs are Corsair DDR4 3000MHz CMK32GBX4M2B3000C15

#### Update

one of the other computers specs are:

[Asus Z170-P](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z170-P/), [i7 6700T](http://ark.intel.com/products/88200/Intel-Core-i7-6700T-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz), 32GB Ram, GTX 1080

And RAMs are the same in all computers.

Comment: What are the other computers?

Comment: I have updated the info, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer](https://github.com/lyonel/lshw/blob/master/src/core/dmi.cc#L1198) is simple, really:

```
// Memory Controller (obsolete in DMI 2.1+)
// therefore ignore the entry if the DMI version is recent enough
```

This piece of code has been like that since almost 11 years.

Why would a newer system have an older DMI version? Who knows. :)

DMI is known to be super unreliable anyway.

You can check the version using `lshw -C system`.

Comment: I have checked that they all have `dmi-3.0`, anyway. Can I assume that missing `memory controller`  does not affect any gpu-cpu data transfer?

Comment: It is not missing. A modern PC cannot function without a memory controller. It is advisable to simply ignore DMI.